# How to run a .jar file from a java program

Tags: java, jar, execute

Ok, I figured out how to run a .exe from this program, but I don't know how to run a .jar.

```
package com.Kaelinator;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ServerManager {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            System.out.println("Opening");
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("D:/Program Files/Sony/Vegas Pro 12.0/vegas");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Closing");
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }
```

That will run Sony Vegas Pro, wait 10 seconds, and then close it.
Here's what I have so far, trying to get to run a .jar:

```
package com.Kaelinator;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ServerManager {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            System.out.println("Opening");
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec(" java -jar " + "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/minecraft_server.15w51b");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Closing");
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

No error about not finding the file, nor any error at all. The program runs like it would, just without opening anything.

Please help!

Comment: what happen when you run `java -jar C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/minecraft_server.15w51b` in cmd?  can you open it by double clicking ?

Comment: @FastSnail Hah, no I can't, double clicking it doesn't work, and also cmd gives me an error. "unable to access jar file". but I'm trying with a different jar file, "JSonSign" and It'll  do the same thing in cmd and my program.

Comment: when you run it from java program you cannot see a cmd .if you read the output then you can get the message .but if cannot run it manually then how can you test from java

Comment: @FastSnail I lied, I didn't put ".jar" at the end of JSonSign when I put it in cmd and my program. My bad XD Anyway, that actually helped, I'm gonna try re-installing minecraft_server.15w51b again. Thank you!

Comment: @FastSnail is there a way to set the answer to this question as your comment?